# CEL files processing: are all cel files raw data?

Tags: bioinformatics

Using affymetrix data, I have always thought that "CEL files" Represent raw data that need to be processed (normalized for example) before being really used.

Nevertheless on the GEO Omnibus web site, when you look at CEL files for some studies (not all: please look at the example with this link: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM467778),

you can read that the values of GSM467778_50.CEL correspond to: "RMA normalised signal intensities" (in the example above) which is not what I call "raw values".

Therefore I don't really know if in this example, I should normalize the cel files or if it is already done ?

Comment: the author of that particular GEO page is likely confused. CEL files apart from being un-normalised are probe-level not gene/feature summarised. PS not really an R question??

Comment: To answer to CathG, it's right at the top of the data table.

Comment: To answer to Stephen, I could give many other examples were the description of values in the "GEO" CEL files seem to be normalized values.  Here's another one : GSE13799 in which MAS5.0 signal intensity is displayed.

Comment: Correction: the author of that page is not confused. The data in the table you are looking at is not the data in the CEL files. When you submit expression data to GEO they ask for both summarised data (like in the table) and the raw data CEL files in case people want to download them.

Comment: I was able to download the CEL file and look at what's inside. Indeed these are Raw values. In fact what was confusing (at least for me) is that when you click on the name of a CEL file, GeO Omnibus can give you (depending on the studies) something else than raw values